# What is the Docker URL on a proget instance

Tags: docker, docker-api, proget

We are using Proget as our Docker Repository of choice and we are running into size issues rapidly. There isn't a good mechanism to prune pre-releases or old images that are no longer needed like there is for other artifacts.

I am using Docker.Dotnet nuget library and have a process where I can connect to a Docker API, evaluate the images using their tags and label or purge what has aged out.

The issue I am running into is that I cannot find the Docker API URL:Port anywhere. My current setup is myrepo.com/docker (and is what I have registered locally), but I cannot connect my Docker client to it.

We are planning on migrating away from this repository anyhow, but this would apply for any other docker repository of choice. For example, what is the URL of the docker hub for API interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the [ProGet Retention Rules](https://docs.inedo.com/docs/proget/administration/retention-rules)? There's a section on Container rules that seems to already purge what you want...